# Communications Link Failure, MySQL database on localhost not connecting

Tags: java, mysql, networking, jdbc

I am attempting to setup a MySQL 5.6 database to work with my application. While working with it however, I cannot seem to get any sort of connection happening. This is the error message I am getting...

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1137)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:356)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2504)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2323)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at ServerDatabase.<init>(ServerDatabase.java:25)
at Server.main(Server.java:60)

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:258)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:306)
... 16 more
```

I have looked up this problem extensively, however I cannot find a solution that fixes my specific problem. The closest I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358) however I followed the steps and got no result. Here is a code snippet to help diagnose...

```
public ServerDatabase() {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dbname", "dev", "**********");
```

I also have the MySQL information for that user account...

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for dev@%                                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'dev'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*C52E324F3EA43A030DCB940689107C77F44391E4' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Some other quick asides to hopefully narrow down responses...

1. I have totally disabled my Windows Firewall, and do not run any other firewall for my local network.
2. the bind-address on my.cnf was not set originally, I set it to 0.0.0.0 with no result so I removed it from the setup.

> [mysqld]
>
> # The next three options are mutually exclusive to SERVER_PORT
>   below.
>      # skip-networking
>      # enable-named-pipe
>      # The Pipe the MySQL Server will use
>      # socket=mysql
>
> # The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
>      port=9118
>
> #bind-address = 127.0.0.1

```
3. I am able to connect using the MySQL command line prompt no problem, and setup the database already.
```

Comment: I assume that "dbname" is the actual name of your DB?

Comment: Yes, I just changed it for this.

Comment: as you have used `dev` as the username make sure u have created a user by the name dev and specified password from root account and granted priviledges to it

Comment: As the grant message has shown, I have already created the user account and granted it proper privileges. I don't think this is the issue, as the error given in my post indicates that no connection was established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me, and likely will work for anyone else who is interested or experiencing problems outside the programming aspect. I would like to clarify, this is the easy way out and may not meet everyones needs. I am a Java Developer, and I can issue SQL commands fairly proficiently. I am not however, a server administrator or anything of the sort. For me this works perfectly.

**Step 1.** 
Download WAMP server. http://www.wampserver.com/en/#download-wrapper

**Step 2.** 
Install + Setup. Follow the instructions on their website for more details.

**Step 3.** Set the server to online by right clicking the WAMP icon. After that you can log into it using the MySQL console provided (the password/username at the time of posting was root // password). The defaults may have changed.

After doing that, I was able to instantly connect to the MySQL database using JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your bind-address in my.cnf

```
"#bind-address = 127.0.0.1"
```

restart mysql

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Comment: Tried that, here is an section of the my.cnf file. Also I am using Windows 8.1.